# Not able to configure Ignite Web session clustering

Tags: java, ignite

I have integrate latest ignite for cache and web session clustering ...while session caching i got an error

```
- Failed to update web session: null
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.bizmatics.prognocis.view.MenuHistoryView
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:604)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:514)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionFilter.doFilterV2(WebSessionFilter.java:562)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionFilter.doFilterDispatch(WebSessionFilter.java:407)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionFilter.doFilter(WebSessionFilter.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.bizmatics.common.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.bizmatics.prognocis.view.MenuHistoryView
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionV2.getAttribute(WebSessionV2.java:209)
    at org.apache.jsp.scrBannMenu_jsp._jspService(scrBannMenu_jsp.java:1362)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.bizmatics.prognocis.view.MenuHistoryView
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionV2.unmarshal(WebSessionV2.java:345)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionV2.getAttribute(WebSessionV2.java:206)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.bizmatics.prognocis.view.MenuHistoryView
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10174)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionV2.unmarshal(WebSessionV2.java:342)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: com.bizmatics.prognocis.view.MenuHistoryView
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:707)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1758)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadCollection(BinaryUtils.java:2072)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1917)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:313)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10168)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bizmatics.prognocis.view.MenuHistoryView
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8775)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:698)
    ... 50 more
```

Client Configuration

Web.xml

```
 <listener>
            <listener-class>org.apache.ignite.startup.servlet.ServletContextListenerStartup</listener-class>
        </listener>

         <filter>
           <filter-name>IgniteWebSessionsFilter</filter-name>
           <filter-class>org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <!-- You can also specify a custom URL pattern. -->
         <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>IgniteWebSessionsFilter</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!-- Specify Ignite configuration (relative to META-INF folder or Ignite_HOME). -->
         <context-param>
           <param-name>IgniteConfigurationFilePath</param-name>
           <param-value>../WEB-INF/default-config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- Specify the name of Ignite cach`e for web sessions. -->
         <context-param>
           <param-name>IgniteWebSessionsCacheName</param-name>
           <param-value>session-cache</param-value>
         </context-param>
```

default-config.xml

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
     <!--<property name="marshaller">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller"/>
    </property>-->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
         <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
             <property name="addresses">
               <list>

                <value>10.2.0.224:47500..47509</value>

               </list>
             </property>
            </bean>
         </property>
     </bean>
   </property>
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="session-cache"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>

                <property name="onheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/>

                <property name="evictionPolicy">
                <!-- LRU eviction policy. -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
                    <!-- Set the maximum cache size to 1 million (default is 100,000). -->
                  <property name="maxSize" value="1000000"/>
                </bean>
              </property>

            </bean>

        </property>

  </bean>
```

Java Source :

```
IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
                                            .setCacheConfiguration(new CacheConfiguration<String, String>()
                                            .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
                                            .setOnheapCacheEnabled(true)
                                            .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC)
                                            .setName("Cache")
                                            .setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, asTimeout)))
                ).setClientMode(true)
                 .setMetricsLogFrequency(0).setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);


                DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
                storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setInitialSize(512L * 1024 * 1024).setMaxSize(2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);

                igniteCfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);
                Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteCfg);

                Cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("Cache")
```

;

Server Configuration :

default-xml :

```
bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="workDirectory" value="D:/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/work" />
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
         <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
             <property name="addresses">
               <list>

                <value>10.2.0.224:47500..47509</value>
                <!--<value>10.2.1.11:47500..47509</value>
                <value>10.10.17.3:47500..47509</value>-->
               </list>
             </property>
            </bean>
         </property>
     </bean>
   </property>
<!-- Redefining maximum memory size for the cluster node usage. -->  
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
    <!-- Redefining the default region's settings -->
    <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">

      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">

        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
        <!-- Setting the size of the default region to 2GB. -->

        <property name="maxSize" value="#{2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="false"/>

      </bean>

    </property>
  </bean>
</property>

<!-- The rest of the parameters. -->
</bean>
```

MenuHistoryView is a class which implements Serializable and has been store in arraylist and arraylist has been store in session

I have also try changing default binary marshaller to optimized marshaller and jdk marshaller but not able to get the fix

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this class, `com.bizmatics.prognocis.view.MenuHistoryView`, on all nodes? I can see that you have onheap caching enabled, which would suggest you need this class on server nodes also.

You should also avoid describing this cache twice (in Java and in XML) since only one configuration will be used, anyway.

Comment: I don't see how persistence is relevant here. Please make sure you have this class on all nodes which are using sessions. As you can see, it is your own class.

Comment: could you help me how to make sure is class present on all nodes or not...i have only one server and on client server no backups

Comment: It's your class, only you can figure out whether it is needed or not. Is it possible that you removed or renamed it while keeping old sessions around? In this case, clearing caches may help.